# Are AppImages architecture dependent

Tags: linux, packages

I am trying to install ["IPE"](http://ipe.otfried.org/) in 32-bit Ubuntu. The website provides AppImage file which is supposed to work for Linux. They didn't provide any 32-bit specific AppImage. Which leads me to ask this question.

Are AppImages architecture dependent? Can there be AppImages which will work in both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems?

([AppImage website](https://appimage.org/) gives only 64-bit examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AppImages are architecture dependent.

[This page](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/Creating-AppImages) of AppImage Wiki on GitHub has mentioned briefly under "Processor Architecture" for creating AppImages. Relevant text has been quoted at below.

> **Can I build multiple-arch (say x86_64 + armhf) AppImages ?**
>
> **No**, you need one AppImage for each architecture. FatELF could solve this, but is not merged into the mainline kernel, so it is currently not an option.

Based on above information, a single AppImage will likely not run on both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems (at least to this answered date).

Following above, you might have this question: "I see only AppImage files for 64-bit, does anyone ever build AppImage for 32-bit?"

Yes, at least one person did. In late February 2016, [issue #91](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/91) at AppImage/AppImageKit on GitHub has mentioned to provide binaries for 32-bit. Under that issue, [this comment](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/91#issuecomment-189685879) had noted the attempt.

> **Provide binaries for x86 (32bit)** #91
>
> [...] shoogle commented on Feb 28, 2016
>
> I managed to get 32 bit AppImage builds of MuseScore to work on Travis.

Considering [the pull request](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/pull/112) was made in March 2016 and relatively new to this answered date, perhaps that is why we hardly see any 32-bit AppImages until now.